# Proper way of passing parametric filenames to \openin using xstring

Tags: expansion, filesystem-access

I would like to open a file programmatically within latex depending on its filename. For example, if the filenames begin with '0' I know the path is in some folder, if it starts with '1' in another folder. To do so, I use the package xstring.
This is due to an old folder structure that cannot be changed now.

This is a MWE (probably can be still reduced)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}

\begin{document}  
\newcommand{\ifA}[2]{\StrBefore{#1}{.}[\stripprefix]\if\ifnum\stripprefix<100 T\else F\fi T%
    #2\fi%    
}    
\newcommand{\ifB}[2]{\StrBefore{#1}{.}[\stripprefix]\if\ifnum\stripprefix>100 T\else F\fi T%
    #2\fi%    
}    

\newcommand{\sourcePath}[1]{%
    \ifA{#1}{a}%    
    \ifB{#1}{b}%    
}    

\newcommand{\procedureFile}[1]{%
    \sourcePath{#1}/#1% 
}    

\newread\fid    
\newcommand{\procRef}[1]{
    \openin\fid=\procedureFile{#1}%
        \read\fid to \instring%
    \closein\fid%   
}    

\procedureFile{012.345} \par
\procedureFile{112.345} \par
\procRef{112.345} 
\instring    
\end{document}
```

The folder structure is like this:

```
./main.tex
./a/012.345.tex    <--- contain string 'AAA'
./b/112.345.tex    <--- contain string 'BBB'
```

If I compile, I get

```
a/012.345
b/112.345
b/112.345
```

whereas I would expect something like

```
a/012.345
b/112.345
BBB
```

I suspect it is related to the expansion of \procedureFile within \procRef, but I can't debug further or solve it.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: `\StrBefore` is not expandable and the files are never opened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\StrBefore` is not expandable and you need to access to the filename by pure expansion.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\chooseAB}[3]{%
  \chooseAB@aux{#2}{#3}#1\@nil
}
\def\chooseAB@aux#1#2#3.#4\@nil{%
  \ifnum#3<100 #1\else #2\fi
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\sourcePath}[1]{%
  \chooseAB{#1}{a}{b}%
}    

\newcommand{\procedureFile}[1]{%
  \sourcePath{#1}/#1%
}

\newread\fid
\newcommand{\procRef}[1]{%
  \openin\fid=\procedureFile{#1}%
  \read\fid to \instring
  \closein\fid
}    

\begin{document}

\procedureFile{012.345} \par
\procedureFile{112.345} \par
\procRef{112.345} 
\instring    

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you need more cases, a “string switch” is better; the choice is made on the first character of the argument, rather than with integers.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% here the correspondence between digits and directories
% is defined
\cs_new:Nn \dabbede_proc_dirfromfile:n
 {
  \str_case_x:nnF { \tl_head:n { #1 } }
   {
    {0}{a}
    {1}{b}
    {2}{c}
   }
   {???}
 }

\ior_new:N \g_dabbede_proc_read_stream

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\procFile}{m}
 {
  \dabbede_proc_dirfromfile:n { #1 } / #1
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\procRef}{m}
 {
  \ior_open:Nx \g_dabbede_proc_read_stream
   {% build the file name
    \dabbede_proc_dirfromfile:n { #1 } / #1
   }
  \ior_map_inline:Nn \g_dabbede_proc_read_stream { ##1 \par }
  \ior_close:N \g_dabbede_proc_read_stream
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \ior_open:Nn { Nx }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\procFile{012.345} \par
\procFile{112.345} \par
\procFile{223.567} \par
\procRef{012.345} \par
\procRef{112.345} \par
\procRef{223.567} \par

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Impressive! This works and helps me a lot. However, why the following is not working? `\newcommand{\sourcePath}[1]{
 \ifnum#1<100 a\else \ifnum#1<200 b\else c\fi\fi
} ` ? What is the purpose of the \chooseAB@aux definition? Is it used to strip the first part of the number? Why do I need the @nil command? Thanks

Comment: @dabbede The purpose of `\@nil` is to say `#4` is everything from up to `\@nil`; `#3` is everything after the first two arguments up to (and excluding) `.`.

Comment: Cool! Now I've got it! I can avoid using \makeatletter by using other characters, for example `\def\dotlhs|#1.#2|{#1}` and calling later something like `\ifnum\dotlhs|#1|<100 a ...` etc. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @dabbede I added macros for managing more cases.

Comment: how can I change your code to handle both explicit command call and "parametric" call? I mean both `\procFile{112.345}` and `\def\proc{012.345}~\procFile{\proc}`? In the final version I would need to use a "foreach" loop...

Comment: I found a solution modifying the definition of **\procedureFile** with `\expandafter\sourcePath\expandafter{#1}/#1%`. I don't know if it is the safest/cleanest way but now it works.